# Flip x and y axes for Matplotlib imshow()

Tags: image, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I'm using `pyplot` with `matplotlib`, and I would like to display some data as an image. When I use `imshow()` the data is flipped from the way I want to view it. How would I switch the x and y axes, either with `imshow()` or to the `numpy` array before I send it to `imshow()`?

(i.e. I want the horizontal axis to be vertical)

I've tried using `origin='upper'` and `origin='lower'` in the `imshow()` command, but that just reverses one axis instead of switching them around

I've also tried using `reshape` on the data, but the order gets all messed up

Comment: Transpose the numpy array. `arr=arr.T`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To close out the question-

You need to transpose the numpy array before passing it to `matplotlib`:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
>>> a=a.T
>>> a
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 3]])
```

So using `plt` it should simply be:

```
plt.imshow(a.T)
```

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning in your answer that you can just pass the origin keyword to imshow.

Comment: How does that exchange x and y axis? That’s just flipping the y-axis on itself?

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye No, transpose switches the X and Y axes. You can see in the example that the diagonal remains the same (which is not the case when flipping only one axis).

Comment: dor00012 sorry, I was replying to the comment from @pelson above, because the origin keyword does indeed only flip the y-axis.

Comment: The matplotlib method `imshow` reads the 2d array "line by line", so that `imshow(a)` will show `a[0]` in the first line, and so on.
But for data that is supposed to be plotted a[x,y] on a x (right), y (up) plot (like for example generated by `numpy.histogram2d`), you indeed need to transpose the data.
Always make sure how the data you want to work with or plot is stored.