# matplotlib flip x and y

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, matplotlib

I had a question on how matplotlib worked. Basically, I want to flip x and y in my image just as [this person asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237169/flip-x-and-y-axes-for-matplotlib-imshow/18237342#18237342?newreg=fa5d957200d44afc8b07b226d7702ff8).

However, I do not want to resort to transposing the array before sending it.

I assume this would result in a loss of performance. Now here is my reasoning. My guess is that matplotlib probably tries to copy an image from numpy to matplotlib by iterating over the rapidly varying index in both (where rapidly varying index here is assumed the index that leads to accessing contiguous elements in physical memory). If I transpose the array, one of two cases can probably happen:

1. What matplotlib thinks to be the rapidly varying index in memory is no longer true and thus it will no longer be accessing the numpy array in a memory contiguous fashion, resulting in slower readout. (i.e. numpy just changes it's "view" into the matrix)
2. The Numpy array is actually copied into a new array where the rapidly varying index is transposed. The reading into matplotlib is fast at the cost of copying a new matrix into memory.

Both of these cases are not ideal in my case as I would like to achieve reasonably high refresh rates. The arrays are loaded from images already stored on a hard drive stored in this fashion.

If my assumption is true, is there some method to have matplotlib change its rapidly varying index for the case of an image? This would be a very useful feature I believe.

I hope to have communicated my line of reasoning. I want to make sure every read and write in the chain is memory contiguous, from the hard drive to the numpy array to matplotlib. I believe that simply finding (or offering in the future) an option for matplotlib to reverse its method of ordering would save time.

I am definitely open to other solutions. If there's something obvious I have missed, I'd like to hear it thanks :-)

---

**Edit:** Thanks for the comments. I believe you are right in that I should have done some testing before hand. I have an interesting result. The transpose seems to be faster than the non-transpose. Since the numpy reference is simply a view into the array, it is possible matplotlib uses this to its advantage to cleverly decide whether or not to transpose last minute? This results suggests so, that or my code has a flaw (which is very possible). Seriously, if that's true, good friggin' job matplotlib developers! :-)

Here are the figures:

Figure 1 : Transposed image (blue) and non transposed image (green). Each data point is the time taken to draw all 10 frames in sequence. This is repeated 100 times. I did not use the machine for the duration of these experiments.

[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2 : Zoom of same figure

[image: Figure 2]

The code (it's crude, learning and limited time to spend on this. I ran the first one for 1000 frames, closed the window, uncommented the second animation, commented the first and ran again for 1000 frames then plotted the two.):

```
`   
    from matplotlib.pyplot import *
    from matplotlib import animation
    from time import time
    import pylab
    import numpy as np

    data = np.random.random((10,1000,1000))

    ion()
    fig = figure(0)

    im = imshow(data[0,:,:])

    data[0,:,:] *= 0

    time1 = time()
    time0 = time()
    timingarraynoT =  np.zeros(100)
    timingarrayT =  np.zeros(100)

    def animatenoT(i):
        global time0,time1,timingarraynoT
        if(i%10==0):
            time0 = time()
        if(i%10 == 9):
            time1 = time()
            #print("Time for 10 frames: {}".format(time1-time0))
            timingarraynoT[i/10] = time1-time0
        im.set_data(data[i%10,:,:])
        if(i == 1000):
            return -1
        return im

    def animateT(i):
        global time0,time1,timingarrayT
        if(i%10==0):
            time0 = time()
        if(i%10 == 9):
            time1 = time()
            #print("Time for 10 frames: {}".format(time1-time0))
            timingarrayT[i/10] = time1-time0
        im.set_data(data[i%10,:,:].T)
        if(i == 1000):
            return -1
        return im

    #anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animateT,interval=0)
    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animatenoT,interval=0)
`
```

Comment: You want to flip the x and y, but you don't want to transpose.... that is the definition of transposing

Comment: Yeah, I think I haven't communicated the idea clearly. Is it correct to assume that when matplotlib draws the image, it probably has to write this image to somewhere in memory. When it does so, it might have to transpose, or might not have to.

What if it has to do a transpose? Then if I have to transpose my image to matplotlib only for it to also have to transpose its image before drawing, that is inefficient. Might as well let matplotlib take care of all the transposing. If all this is true (I am making a lot of assumptions, so please correct me if I'm wrong), I'd rather not transpose myimg.

Comment: (It might have to transpose depending on how the array is stored in memory for the graphics card or whatever etc. sorry for the long comment)

Comment: I doubt that the transpose operator will drop your performance. Even `data.T.copy()` which makes a contiguous copy of the data should be fast enough to give you decent frame rates (unless your image is ridiculously big). Are you sure this is the bottleneck of your implementation?

Comment: I would bet quite a large sum of money that this is not going to be the performance bottleneck in your code. The I/O and the actual plotting are much more likely to slow you down.

Comment: Thanks imaluengo. I have gone ahead and tested it. I found the transpose to be faster (see figures linked to in current edit). I am confused by the result. Is it possible matplotlib is clever enough with numpy arrays do draw efficiently? I am very curious. In either case, the difference is negligible in my case. Thanks again. If you post as an actual response I'll mark it as an answer that resolves my question.
(Oh forgot to mention this strange result would make sense under the assumption the graphics card requires to transpose the array before drawing from the first case)